# iOS design guidelines like Android's?

Tags: interface-design, ios, design-specifications

What are the standards for designing iOS apps? By standards I mean rules for margins, paddings, font sizes, etc. that should be followed when designing an iOS app. Are there any rules?

To clarify what I mean, [here is the link](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) for Android's design guidelines, which are very detailed. Is there anything like this for iOS?

Comment: [Related question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/44853/23061)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html)

The iOS Human Interface Guidelines set out guidelines for general design principles to follow, specific guidelines on typography, color, navigation, interactivity, icons and a lot more.

Apple aren't very strict on enforcing these design guidelines (not consistently anyway) so not all apps you see will follow these guidelines and a lot of designers probably won't read through the whole documentation.

One thing to take in to consideration is that some iOS UI elements are more customisable than others. For example, you can change fonts and colors on most elements but the sizes of navigation bars or pickers can't easily be changed.