# I cant find iOS specs equivalent to Material Design

Tags: interface-design, ios, apple, style-guide

I work in a small company where I already did the design for an app using Material Design guidelines but now I have to design the iOS version; maybe I got used to Material guidelines but I can't find the equivalent of that for iOS, so far I have this massive official website (https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/) where they explain the "why" of everything and I'm reading it... still... no specs at all.

Do I have to download Sketch (maybe it has its own iOS library) or how do I get the measures?

Im guessing that the answer is going to be very obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS design guidelines like Android's?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69644/ios-design-guidelines-like-androids)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/) *are* the official guidelines and the closest official source you'll get. There is no detailed spec similar to Material Design's.

Although similar in purpose, the Human Interface Guidelines and Material Design Guidelines are different for a reason. Material Design is a conscious attempt to create a single design system for a unified experience across platforms and devices. It is intended to be a consistent visual language. Apple have no similar intent (at least not in a practically applicable way), you're free to design as you wish.

It's worth pointing out that you *can* design for iOS using Material Design. Google's own iOS apps certainly do.

If all you're after is iOS's native UI elements in a PSD/Sketch file then there are plenty of third party kits available. A few examples:

- [**iOS 9 Complete UI (free Sketch+PSD for iPhone 5, 6 and 6 Plus)**](https://dribbble.com/shots/2255601-ios-9-complete-ui-free-psds-for-iphone-5-6-and-6-plus)
- [**iOS 10 UI (GUI) kit for Sketch and Photoshop**](http://ozzik.co/freebies/ios10kit)
- [**TETHR — Beautiful (and free) iOS design kit**](https://www.invisionapp.com/tethr)

Answer (score 2):

Also this can be useful for you :)

[image]